# Why does this code block returns error in codewars test cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, array-push

Consider the following question from [codewars kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5502c9e7b3216ec63c0001aa/train/javascript):

> The Western Suburbs Croquet Club has two categories of membership, Senior and Open. They would like your help with an application form that will tell prospective members which category they will be placed.
> To be a senior, a member must be at least 55 years old and have a handicap greater than 7. In this croquet club, handicaps range from -2 to +26; the better the player the lower the handicap.
> Input
> Input will consist of a list of lists containing two items each. Each list contains information for a single potential member. Information consists of an integer for the person's age and an integer for the person's handicap.
> Example Input
> `[[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]`
> Output
> Output will consist of a list of string values (in Haskell: Open or Senior) stating whether the respective member is to be placed in the senior or open category.
> Example Output
> `["Open", "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Open", "Senior"]`

Now consider my code:

```js
function openOrSenior(data){
  let output = [];
  for (i=0 ; i < data.length; i++){
    if (data[i][i] > 54 && data[i][(i+1)] > 7){
      output.push('Senior')
    } else { output.push('Open') };
  }
  return output;
}
```

This code returns an error when running test cases:

```
Unhandled rejection TestError: Expected: '[\'Open\', \'Senior\', \'Open\', \'Senior\']', instead got: '[\'Open\', \'Open\', \'Open\', \'Open\']'
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with my code.
The link to the kata is [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5502c9e7b3216ec63c0001aa/train/javascript).

Answer (score 2):

`data[i][i]` doesn't make any sense. The age and handicap will be in `data[i][0]` and `data[i][1]` respectively.

While you could fix the indices, a cleaner approach would be to do

```
const openOrSenior = data => data.map(([age, handicap]) => (
  (age >= 55 && handicap > 7) ? 'Senior' : 'Open'
));
```

The `([age, handicap]) => (` will extract the 0th and 1st items from each subarray being iterated over, putting the 0th into a variable named `age`, and the 1st into a variable named `handicap`. This is called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).